# How to circulate cool air into bedrooms through narrow hallway?

Tags: air-conditioning

I have recently installed a window air conditioner in the living room area of my apartment, which is the appropriate BTU for the whole apartment. It’s been working amazingly up to the doorway of the bedrooms, which are in a narrow hallway. I’ve been using one air circulator to push the air into the hallway, but it hasn’t really been able to cool the entirety of either bedroom at all.

I am not allowed to install window ACs in the bedrooms.Should I just buy another air circulator fan to push more air into the rooms themselves? Am I misunderstanding how cold air flow works (I have been pointing the fan so it would hit the top of the doorways)?

Somebody please help me, it’s been so incredibly frustrating after all the work I went through to install the AC in the first place.

[image]

Comment: What is between the bedroom lines and the living room lines(besides empty black space)?  You might need fans to push/pull air out of the bedrooms, besides pushing in one way.

Answer (score 3):

To do this well you probably need one fan pointing into the hall and two more to push air from the hall into the bedrooms.  Put them on the floor - cold air sinks, hot air rises.  Small fans that push air fast would be better than box fans that move a lot of air slowly.

Comment: The drawback to small fans moving air quickly is that they make far more noise than a box fan, which makes _more_ than enough noise to keep me awake at night...

Comment: I think the real problem here is that you can push cold air into the hallway, but you need to be able to pull hot air out—otherwise circulation is difficult no matter how many fans you have directed at the hallway.  Perhaps a fan near the ceiling to pull hot air out, and one near the floor to push cold air in.

Answer (score 2):

My son, when in Oregon, (104 deg summers) had the same issue. Only had a wall AC unit in the kitchen. (Same room layout as you have. AC unit in the front room on the left wall.)

He had a pedestal fan at the entrance of the hall set at about 3 feet high. Pointed at the bedrooms and running at med. speed, it kept him in his bedroom and his mother and me in ours cool so we could sleep.